# Siamese for two, which word for four?

Tags: synonyms

We use *Siamese* for two, such as Siamese twins. Which word should be used when the number is four in such situation?

Comment: We use ***twins*** for two.

Comment: *Siamese twins* are [conjoined twins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjoined_twins). If somehow there were four conjoined siblings, they would be *Siamese quadruplets*.

Comment: *Conjoined quadruplets.* "Siamese" as a term for conjoined twins has been deprecated since at least the '80s, when I was in journalism school.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is mistaken: we do not “use *Siamese* for two”. Things that come in twos are variously known as *pairs*, *couples*, *doubles*, or *twins*.

There is no common word denoting something that regularly comes in quadruplicate, apart perhaps from a *foursome* or as mentioned in comments, a *quartet*.

But that doesn’t express the same notion as Siamese twins does. You must be thinking of the famous [conjoined twins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjoined_twins) of their day, [Chang and Eng Bunker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chang_and_Eng_Bunker).  I have never heard of conjoined quadruplets surviving.

The OED also mentions [Siamese cats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siamese_cat), [Siamese fighting fish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siamese_fighting_fish), and [Siamese pheasants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siamese_fireback).  None of those need come in twos.

Comment: Quartet for things that come in fours.  Most often used to describe a musical group - e.g. string quartet, barbershop quartet - but I've also seen it used in math and physics contexts.

Comment: @jamesqf In some places, yes.  But if you had two pairs of kings in a poker hand, you wouldn’t call them a *quartet*.

Comment: Agreed, but you wouldn't call a single pair of kings a couple (ok, maybe), double, or twins.  Also, twins implies identical, so if you have twin kings (of spades, say), vocabulary is going to be the least of your worries :-)

Comment: @jamesqf I would not say that *twins* implies monozygotic duplicates, given that **most** twins are dizygotic! The chance of having twins at all is one birth in 30, but that of having identical twins a far scanter one birth in 285.